# How to open up device credential check using a Biometric Prompt?

Tags: java, android, credentials, prompt, biometrics

I got an application where users can choose to login using their fingerprint or the given device credential (pin etc.) after their first login. The fingerprint part is working fine using a `new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()` and some given title and negative button for cancelling. Now I would like to make another part for device credential check, when the user has chosen this login method in the app. So I have added `.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` to the `BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()` (which shows a "Use PIN" -button for fallback instead of Cancel -button).

Is it possible to disable the fingerprint part and get access to "Use PIN" -button immediately so that the user can authenticate using their PIN?

Comment: I'm having quite similar requirement. were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Have already left this project behind, but no didn't get it resolved. Think I left it so that user has to make one extra click for the PIN authentication.